# Wanting to make CNN ( resnet18) and LSTM combined with pytorch library

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am figuring out how to make CNN (resnet18) and LSTM model combined with pytorch library, but I have no idea how. Been trying this code, but it showed "optimizer got an empty parameter list"

```
class Combine(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Combine, self).__init__()
        self_res = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
        self = self_res.to(device)
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=320, 
            hidden_size=64, 
            num_layers=1,
            batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(64,3)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size, timesteps, C, H, W = x.size()
        c_in = x.view(batch_size * timesteps, C, H, W)
        c_out = self.cnn(c_in)
        r_in = c_out.view(batch_size, timesteps, -1)
        r_out, (h_n, h_c) = self.rnn(r_in)
        r_out2 = self.linear(r_out[:, -1, :])
        
        return F.log_softmax(r_out2, dim=1)


class Args:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cuda = True
        self.no_cuda = False
        self.seed = 1
        self.batch_size = 50
        self.test_batch_size = 1000
        self.epochs = 10
        self.lr = 0.01
        self.log_interval = 10

model = Combine()
args = Args()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
#optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)
```

I am expecting a cnn (resnet18) and lstm model combined for classification task with 3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the initialization of the model and the deployment on CUDA are mixed.

Remove `self_res.to(device)`
Add `model.to(device)` later.